# SQL Error when using CTE inside THEN of CASE expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, correlated-subquery, case-statement

**EDIT:**

Tried changing it to the following (moved CTE to the top).

I now get get the error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.

I tried putting a very simply select in the second 'THEN' clause that didn't even use the cte and I get the same error. Seems not to like any sub query in the second then?

```
 WITH MainCTE AS (
      SELECT DISTINCT rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                  ORDER BY u.PLANNED_DATE
                               )
             ,u.name
             ,u.order
             ,u.unit_code
             ,u.mode
             ,u.[SEQUENCE]
             ,u.PLANNED_DATE
             ,City = left(SUBSTRING(name, CHARINDEX(':', name) + 1, CHARINDEX(',', name)), charindex(',', SUBSTRING(name, CHARINDEX(':', name) + 2, CHARINDEX(',', name))))
             ,StateAbbrv = SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(name, CHARINDEX(':', name) + 1, LEN(name)), CHARINDEX(',', SUBSTRING(name, CHARINDEX(':', name) + 1, LEN(name))) + 1, 4)
       FROM TableU u
       INNER JOIN TableT T ON u.ordnum = t.ordnum
       INNER JOIN TableR R ON t.CustNum = r.CustNum
   )
SELECT DISTINCT o.first_name, 
o.last_name, 
o.phone_number
,CASE t.indicator
    WHEN 2
        THEN (
                SELECT mode
                FROM TableU
                WHERE TypeInd = 'I'
                    AND [DATE] = (
                        SELECT max([DATE])
                        FROM TableU
                        WHERE TypeInd = 'I'
                        )
                )
    WHEN 3
        THEN (
                SELECT DISTINCT maincte.mode AS plannedmode
                    ,maincte.PLANNED_DATE
                    ,maincte.[SEQUENCE]
                FROM maincte
                LEFT JOIN maincte prev ON prev.rownum = maincte.rownum - 1
                LEFT JOIN maincte nex ON nex.rownum = maincte.rownum + 1
                INNER JOIN TableT T ON u.ordnum = t.ordnum
                INNER JOIN TableR R ON t.CustNum = r.CustNum
                    AND maincte.[SEQUENCE] = r.[SEQUENCE]
                    AND t.[DATE] > '01/01/2014'
                ORDER BY maincte.[LOCAL_UNIT_SEQUENCE]
                    ,maincte.PLANNED_UNIT_DATE ASC
            ) 

FROM TableR R 
INNER JOIN TableT T ON t.CustNum = r.CustNum
INNER JOIN TableO O ON t.ordNum = o.OrdNum 
WHERE t.custNum = R.custNum
        AND o.custName = R.CustName
        AND t.indicator IN (
        2
        ,3
        )
        AND r.rstatus = 'Yes' 
ORDER BY t.ordnum
```

My SQL statement below won't run and I'm stumped how to solve it. I've only changed the column and table names.

Using SQL Server 2008 Management Studio

The errors I get are:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'.
>
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression or an xmlnamespaces clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.
>
> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    o.first_name, 
    o.last_name, 
    o.phone_number
    ,CASE t.indicator
       WHEN 2
        THEN (SELECT mode
              FROM TableU
              WHERE TypeInd = 'I'
                AND [DATE] = (SELECT max([DATE])
                              FROM TableU
                              WHERE TypeInd = 'I')
             )
       WHEN 3
        THEN (WITH MainCTE AS (
                        SELECT DISTINCT rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                                ORDER BY u.PLANNED_DATE
                                )
                            ,u.name
                            ,u.order
                            ,u.unit_code
                            ,u.mode
                            ,u.[SEQUENCE]
                            ,u.PLANNED_DATE
                            ,City = left(SUBSTRING(name, CHARINDEX(':', name) + 1, CHARINDEX(',', name)), charindex(',', SUBSTRING(name, CHARINDEX(':', name) + 2, CHARINDEX(',', name))))
                            ,StateAbbrv = SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(name, CHARINDEX(':', name) + 1, LEN(name)), CHARINDEX(',', SUBSTRING(name, CHARINDEX(':', name) + 1, LEN(name))) + 1, 4)
                        FROM TableU u
                        INNER JOIN TableT T ON u.ordnum = t.ordnum
                        INNER JOIN TableR R ON t.CustNum = r.CustNum
                        )
                SELECT DISTINCT maincte.mode AS plannedmode
                    ,maincte.PLANNED_DATE
                    ,maincte.[SEQUENCE]
                FROM maincte
                LEFT JOIN maincte prev ON prev.rownum = maincte.rownum - 1
                LEFT JOIN maincte nex ON nex.rownum = maincte.rownum + 1
                INNER JOIN TableT T ON u.ordnum = t.ordnum
                INNER JOIN TableR R ON t.CustNum = r.CustNum
                    AND maincte.[SEQUENCE] = r.[SEQUENCE]
                    AND t.[DATE] > '01/01/2014'
                ORDER BY maincte.[LOCAL_UNIT_SEQUENCE]
                    ,maincte.PLANNED_UNIT_DATE ASC
            ) 
FROM 
   TableR R 
INNER JOIN 
   TableT T ON t.CustNum = r.CustNum
INNER JOIN 
   TableO O ON t.ordNum = o.OrdNum 
WHERE 
   t.custNum = R.custNum
   AND o.custName = R.CustName
   AND t.indicator IN (2, 3)
   AND r.rstatus = 'Yes' 
ORDER BY 
   t.ordnum
```

Comment: The `with` statement goes before the main `select`.  That is the syntax for CTEs in SQL Server.  But your query has multiple problems.  For instance, it looks like the subqueries would be returning multiple rows and multiple columns in a context where a scalar subquery is expected.

Comment: Your with clause is bringing more than one column which is invalid for the case (then) operator in your statement. It should bring just one column on the select statement returning just one row.

Comment: Shouldn't it run the where clause first? This would narrow it down to one row of values that the select would then use

Comment: Even when I select a top 1, there is no way to put a CTE in the THEN clause?

Comment: You'll often see `;WITH` where the leading semicolon is present to guarantee that any previous statement is terminated.

Comment: Tried that, just got an error that stated incorrect syntax near ";"

Comment: You can *reference* a CTE anywhere in your query, but its *definition* (the WITH clause itself) should go at the beginning of the entire statement: `WITH yourCTE AS (...) /* main statement begins */ SELECT ... whatever ... FROM ...`. You can then have a CASE expression in your main SELECT column list that uses a subquery referencing `yourCTE`. Note, however, that CASE is a *scalar* expression, therefore the subquery that you put after THEN must return exactly one column and at most one row.

Comment: I suspect the problme is that you are using a correlated subquery at all! They are a really poor choice and should almost never be used. Try the CTE as a derived table instead,

Comment: I don't see an `END` for your case statement.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have a CTE within a sub-query however if you move the CTE before the initial query you should be able to access it within the sub-query.

After your edit I looked through your query a little more and saw the following problems:

1) You're missing END at the end of your case statement
2) It is possible to get back multiple rows from your sub-queries in your case statement
3) Your second sub-query is trying to return 3 columns

Comment: I tried this and just had a normal select after the second then so it is now:

Comment: Is there any way you could provide sample data and a sample output given the sample data?

Answer (score 0):

As pyrrosa said you cannot declare a CTE inside a sub-query.  You must declare it at the beginning of a statement.

`WITH` statements require the prior statement to be terminated by a semicolon.  This is why you will often see the semicolon immediately before the WITH statement like this:

```
;WITH MainCTE AS...
```

I expect that this will get around the error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a
>   common table expression or an xmlnamespaces clause, the previous
>   statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

You may get different errors after adding the semicolon.  Subqueries in a `CASE` statement cannot return multiple rows; they must return a single scalar value.  Your `THEN` statement that queries the CTE should return a single scalar value that is somehow related to the current row's values.  Currently, it could return multiple values.

Your query gives me the error:

> Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 46
>
> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.

This is because you can't have the `ORDER BY` in the `THEN` clause, because it can only return a single scalar value.

Also, you cannot return multiple columns in one case and a single column in the other.  If you try to return multiple columns, you will get this error (on SQL Server 2008 R2):

> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
>
> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

You may need a `UNION` of 2 different queries-- but the UNION will have to return the same number of columns.  If that doesn't work for you, maybe you could use separate queries to return different tables.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems with your top query.

1. You are missing the `END` on your case statement. That's why you get the `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.` error.
2. You cannot have an order by in your subquery.